# How to target the absolute path when using file template in Android Studio Arctic Fox?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, android-studio-arctic-fox, file-templates

version: Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 patch 3.

I want to create a Fragment file and let Android Studio generate the layout file for me using the file template feature.

My problem is when create the fragment, the child template always generate the layout file in the same directory as the fragment file. How can I give the absolute path like "/app/res/layout/" for layout xml file? Any ideas?

[image]